# Jetbrains Clion настройка компилятора. Возникла ошибка: Cmake error 51.

Tags: mingw, cmake, jetbrains, clion

Установил Jetbrains Clion 2017.2.3.
Установил MinGW.
В переменной среды PATH указал:

```
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin;
C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin;
```

В настройках Clion прописал путь к MinGW

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее при запуске проекта выводит следующую ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого ставил MinGW 64 ver 5.0, результат такой же.
Имею плохое представление как собирается проект, по этому нет идей как это исправить. Может быть нужно что-то указать в файле CMakeCache.txt, подскажите пожалуйста? Такая же тема была опубликована месяц назад, но на неё не дали ответа, поэтому создал ещё одну тему. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Русские символы в пути к проекту? Попробуйте собрать проект, в котором нет русских символов в пути.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, помогло! Никаких русских символов. Проект собран и все компилируется!